# Simulating sub-uri in RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, uri

In my Rails 3.2 application controller responds with JSON containing an URLs to images (stored with Paperclip). It works ok locally,but links are broken on server, because the application is deployed under a sub URI. I would like to test that everythig works OK with sub-uri, but I don't know how to simulate it in test environment (I use RSpec). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/ebeigarts/5450422) has a section that shows how to setup a relative root for your Rails app when running in RSpec, perhaps it will help.